# Sort Google Search results by date?

Tags: google-search, sorting

Is there a way to sort Google Search results by date?

(I know how to limit the search to a particular time period.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Click 'Search tools' then select any date filter other than 'Any time'.
Then click in the default 'Sorted by relevance' option and select 'Sorted by date'

Comment: Thank you.  I hadn't noticed that!  Your answer motivated me to hunt around for a firefox add-on, and I found one that streamlines things almost as much as I was hoping: Shortcut Keys for Google Search.

Answer (score 8):

No, you cannot change the sort order of Google Search results. The sort order is determined by Google's secret recipe.

All you can do is filter your search for specific time periods.

Comment: @David: No, it really isn't. Your answer is just a quote from the FAQ for "[Google Site Search](https://www.google.com/work/search/products/gss.html)", which is for adding search powered by Google to your own website and only returns your site's content. It doesn't apply to the "normal" Google Search that the OP is asking about.

Comment: See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/80376/88163

Answer (score 4):

[Rubén](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%C3%A9n) and [infrcl](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/72445/infrcl) have good answers.

Here is one way you can sort by date, using **Search Query Parameters**.

Assume you want the last two years sorted by date.

---

1. Search for your term, hit enter

[image]

2. You will get a URL, which includes Search Query Params. Copy it.

[image]

3. Append `&tbs=qdr:y2,sbd:1` to your URL and hit Enter.

[image]

4. Now you will have "Past 2 years" and "Sorted by Date"

[image]

**tbs**: It is a param that is like a container for params.Defines specific structure, such as key:value, and comma delineation between params. https://stenevang.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/google-search-url-request-parameters/

**qdr**: Similar to `as_qdr`(advanced search quick date range). Here you specify date range. `qdr:y2` means, "search within the last two years". You can search by days using `d`, as in `qdr:d10` to search within the last 10 days. Further instruction at  https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results?hl=en#Advanced_Search_Query_Parameters

**sbd**: I believe this is a boolean for sort-by-date.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me when I tried it.

Comment: @aparente001 Ok. Sorry about that, I figured this one out through experimentation and I don't think `tbs` is available in formal docs. However maybe I can help. What happens when you try? Can you send a sample URL thats not working? For instance `https://www.google.com/search?q=cheese&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8` should become `https://www.google.com/search?q=cheese&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&tbs=qdr:y2,sbd:1` and that works for me.

Comment: Tried it again and is working for me -- not sure what I was doing wrong before.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

Google Search doesn't include a way to sort unfiltered search results.

## Alternatives

### Google Search built-in filters

Filter results by any time filter. This will display several dropdowns. One of them if for sorting options including sorting by date. (see [4])

### Google Custom Search

One alternative could be to create your own search engine with Google Custom Search as it allows to search the entire web and include results sorting.

## References

1. [Custom Search Help](https://support.google.com/customsearch)
2. [Search the entire web - Custom Search Help](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2631040?hl=en)
3. [Search Features > Sort results - Custom Search Help](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2549537?hl=en)
4. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/80376/88163
5. [Filter your search results - Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/142143?hl=en)

Comment: This sounds intriguing, @Rubén.  How do I create my own search engine with Google Custom Search?

Comment: Please follow the first reference in my answer.

Comment: am I supposed to make a website that only I can see?  Or what?

Answer (score 2):

To add to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89543 above, there is a hacky way to sort all Google search results from "Any time" by date so you get new results at top without using any time range.

Simply botch the **qdr** parameter by feeding it something other than what it expects like `&tbs=qdr:X` instead of `&tbs=qdr:y2`, `&tbs=qdr:m1`, `&tbs=qdr:d30` or `&tbs=qdr:w4` etc. Now Google will serve results that are sorted by date,newest first and date range will turn to 'Any time'.

Also I noticed that search results can be very inconsistent for a time range if it is defined differently say using `&tbs=qdr:m1` instead of `&tbs=qdr:d30`.

Comment: Sounds promising.  Could you be very specific about how to set this up to work automatically?  My desired end result is to type something into the search box (the address field in Firefox, actually), and for it to automatically give me the results in a sorted-by-date order.  I don't know what you mean by "botch the parameter".

Comment: @aparente001 By botching I simply mean modifying the *qdr* value within URL to something unexpected like changing https://www.google.co.in/#q=some+document&tbs=qdr:w,sbd:1 to https://www.google.co.in/#q=some+document&tbs=qdr:X,sbd:1 To automate on Firefox you could create [Smart Keyword](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-search-from-address-bar) search. I did it by going to URL https://www.google.co.in/#q=some+document&tbs=qdr:X,sbd:1 holding **ctrl** and right clicking on search field. In location bar I enter keyword+'My search string' and get sorted results from anytime! :)

Answer (score 0):

After limiting your search to a time period, change the option "Sorted by relevance" to "Sorted by date" below your search query.

[image: Sorting is right next to the date range option.]

Comment: This was already posted a few days ago.